# How do I change the FOV (Field of View)?

Tags: the-witcher-3

How do I change The Witcher 3's FOV (Field of View)? I've looked around and have read that I can use Cheat Engine to do so.

I have never used Cheat Engine before and I couldn't find any actual good tutorials explaining how to use it to adjust The Witcher 3's FOV. Can someone explain to me how to change The Witcher 3's FOV (through Cheat Engine, or other methods)?

Comment: Did the graphics adjustment help you? This seems to be a very common issue, I'd like to make sure my listed process is correct.

Comment: Sorry for taking long, no it didn't work I have just given up on trying to get it to work now.

Answer (score 4):

[Here, jim2point0](http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=581792&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=30) has posted Cheat Engine tables for Witcher 3 FOV. Confirmed working on Steam or GOG versions.

To use these, you will need to download [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/downloads.php). (Be careful on the install process, there is some "packaged software" that you don't want.)

Once Cheat Engine is installed, you will need to run Witcher 3, and minimize it to open Cheat Engine. This is actually the most difficult part of the process, as Witcher tends to crash when returning to it. To circumvent this, set all graphics settings as low as possible, and enter Windowed mode. This is only temporary.

Run cheat engine, and use the processes selection button[image: That button!]

Now find and select Witcher 3 from the list of running processes, and open it.

Back in the main screen of Cheat Engine, Using the Open button or Ctrl+O, open the Witcher 3 Cheat Table downloaded earlier. Now confirm 'OK' to the dialogue that pops up.

In the bottom pane, you will notice a new entry has appeared[image: Check this box!]

Check the box in the 'Active' section.

Return to Witcher, and revert your graphical settings. You should now be able to use '+' and '-' in game to change your FOV.

Comment: I don't want to learn how to use CE more than necessary that looks extremely long and complicated all I really want to know is how to change the witcher 3 FOV using cheat engine.

Comment: Changing camera settings through CE is higher level use. You can copy the cheat table the first link links to, but if you don't already understand the basics of Cheat Engine, you're not going to have much luck with this. Try asking on the Cheat Engine forums if this isn't helpful enough for you.

Comment: I am starting to think the work I will have to go through to change it will not be enough. This is currently the only way to change it right?

Comment: I can tell you that Cheat Engine is an invaluable tool, and I am often glad that I took the time to learn to use it. I do not know of another way around your problem. However I don't think it should take you long at all to utilize the cheat tables already posted. You just need some base level knowledge on CE. Go through the tutorial in Cheat Engine, and it will teach you the basics of opening programs and changing values. Now load up Witcher and load in the Cheat Table from the first link I posted, and you should be able to run it from there.

Comment: Could use a few more pictures, but I don't have Witcher 3 to make them as accurate as they should be.

Comment: Nope it didn't work... and now my game keeps crashing

Comment: When does it crash? Does it crash when you maximize Witcher, or while its still minimized?

Comment: You know I was assuming you're using the Steam version, but if you aren't then you'll need a different hack table. I'll add that to the Answer when I get it together.

Comment: It crashes when I maximize it I tried pressing + and - a few times to see if it would work then it just crashes. I then closed cheat engine and relaunched it and it worked. I am using the steam version.

Comment: I updated the answer to include some graphical fixes. Witcher apparently doesn't like being sent to the background processes. You should be able to fix it by setting all graphical settings as low as possible, and using Windowed mode while you do the Cheat Engine process, then you can reset all the graphical settings once Witcher is successfully maximized. Are you using the Steam or GOG version of Witcher?